# Using scandir() with Magento

Tags: php, magento

For the home page of my Magento store, I am using a basic gallery script which scans a predefined directory using scandir() and outputs each filename to be displayed in the gallery.

Everything works ok on my local machine, but the script seems to ignore the scandir() and just proceeds as normal without any errors or warnings. If I replace the scandir() and input the filenames directly, the gallery script works fine.

What is going wrong here?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Hard to tell without seeing your code in context, but my guess if `scandir` is returning an empty array, probably because you're not passing it what you think you're passing it.  Add some debugging to your calls to `scandir`

```
$path;
var_dump($path);

$results = scandir($path);
var_dump($results);
```

and you should have a better idea of whats going on.

Comment: How silly of me to forget about var_dump! The scandir is returning false, even though the directory path is valid. Could it be that it is unable to scan a directory that isn't a relative path? I have pass it the full URL to the folder.

Comment: Scandir should work with relative paths, **but** there's a lot of confusion around about how PHP sets the current working directory, and how what functions/methods obey the current working directory.  Try scandir('.') to see where PHP thinks it is, use getcwd() to get a copt of the working directory, and finally, use a full, non relative path if possible.

Comment: Thanks for the tip, Alan. I ended up passing the absolute path via getcwd() and it seemed to work nicely!